# Storing downloaded data on sdcard

Tags: android, caching

Is there any way to save data obtained during app-run and afterwards use it instead of accessing web resources again?

For instance, I have an article with some pictures in it. When a client opens the article the first time, the image is downloaded and stored on his sdcard. So, the next time he accesses the article, he doesn't waste web traffic.

Comment: So you want to implement a caching mechanism in your app ? It is defintely possible, though not trivial, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html

here is a code to download file form URL(file)
and save to sd card.

and use further

you can easily implement for your URL(file)